# Redirect page after submitting form using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form

```
<form class="bar" action="process.php">

</form>
```

My select tag

```
<select id="foo">
<option value="index.php?id=1">Volvo</option>
<option value="index.php?id=2">Saab</option>
</select>
```

If someone change the selected option, I want the form to be submitted and the page redirect to url based on value in selected option

I try

```
$('#foo').on('change', function(){
$('.bar').submit();
 });
```

I find that the form is successfully submitted.

But when I tried to redirect the page using:

```
$('#foo').on('change', function(){
var url = $(this).val();
$('.bar').submit();
if(url){
window.location = url;
}
});
```

the page is successfuly redirected, but the form is not submitted.
Note: I am not planning using ajax

Comment: Did you put the quote into the 'foo' selector? Like this $('#foo') and not $(#foo)?

Comment: If you're submitting the form you need to do the redirect from there, ie. from your `process.php` file

Comment: Updated @Kuartz sorry, I misstyped since I wrote this question from my tablet.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I need to submit the form to process.php and redirect page to url based on selected option value

Comment: @wawanmadda exactly, so do the redirect from `process.php` - it's the *only* way this can work without using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: use `$("#foo")` instead of `$(#foo)`

2nd: On `select` change event .. replace the default form `action` url with the selected value url by using `$('.bar').attr('action' , url)` then submit the form using `.submit()`

See the next example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#foo").on('change', function(){
    var url = $(this).val();
    console.log(url.replace('index','process'));
    $('.bar').attr('action' , url.replace('index','proccess')).submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="bar" action="process.php">
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<select id="foo">
<option value="index.php?id=1">Volvo</option>
<option value="index.php?id=2">Saab</option>
</select>
```

you can replace the action url with `process.php?id=` the id you get from value .. and then in process.php you can use

```
if($_GET['id'] == '1'){
   exit(header("location: index.php?id=1"));
}
if($_GET['id'] == '2'){
   exit(header("location: index.php?id=2"));
}
```

OR *to redirect without if statement*

```
exit(header("location: index.php?id=".$_GET['id']));
```

**Note:** if `exit(header("location: index.php?id=` not redirect to the `index.php` try to use `/index.php?id` , `./index.php?id` , '../index.php?id' , or try it with the full url `http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?id`

Comment: Based on your answer, I checked the http header and found that the form was submitted to index.php?id=1 or 2. I need the form to be submitted to process.php, and the page redirected to index.php?id=1 or 2